# What is the maximum number of Children Views inside a FrameLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I'm tyring use **FrameLayout** with Multiple children within it. I know by using `android:layout_gravity` attribute I can add multiple children to a FrameLayout. But my unclear part is whether it is affecting to the **performance side** and **Cost** side of the app if I add more Children to the FrameLayout

Comment: Why not use ConstraintLayout?

Comment: note that limitation my differ cross different devices as performance score for different devices vary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

roughly 80 is the limit.

you will get following lint when you have too many view in your layout

> AndroidLintTooManyViews
>
> Description
>
> Layout has too many views  Using too many views in a single layout is bad 
>   for performance. Consider using compound drawables or other tricks for 
>   reducing the number of views in this layout.  The maximum view count 
>   defaults to 80 but can be configured with the environment variable 
>   ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT.

note that limitation my differ cross different devices as performance score for different devices vary.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the maximum number of Children Views inside a FrameLayout in Android?

There's no limit indicated on how many children that a `ViewGroup` can have on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup). But you should try to lessen it as much as possible because it will take too long to render and it may cause your app to crash, throwing OutOfMemoryException or StackOverflowException. It was also indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499146/how-many-viewgroup-linearlayout-relative-grid-etc-considered-too-many).

> whether it is affecting to the performance side and Cost side of the app if I add more Children to the FrameLayout

Adding more views will surely takes more time to load than having less views. The proper question I guess is, **what's the efficient way to render views?** Nesting views are inefficient, you should always try to **avoid deep hierarchy** as much as possible and you can achieve this by using `ConstraintLayout`. You can read more about optimizing view hierarchies [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies).